# Четыре FAB в ряд

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Всем добра! Ребят, нужна Ваша помощь. Как поместить *четыре* `FloatingActionButton` в ряд? Пригодится любая помощь! Чтобы получилось так
[image: Чтобы получилось так]

Comment: Нужно именно вот так не ровно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен контейнер, коий элементы в себе расположит один за другим с одинаковой у каждого шириной. Тут поможет `LinearLayout`, с `orientation="horizontal"` и внутренними контейнерами с весом в 1. В контейнеры же уже помещайте `FAB`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:hight="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <FrameLayout
        android:width="0dip"
        android:hight="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1">
    <!-- сюда fab вставляйте -->
    </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
        android:width="0dip"
        android:hight="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1">
    <!-- сюда fab вставляйте -->
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:width="0dip"
        android:hight="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1">
    <!-- сюда fab вставляйте -->
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:width="0dip"
        android:hight="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1">
    <!-- сюда fab вставляйте -->
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: гениально! дай бог Вам здоровья!

Comment: @iFr0z, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

использование множества вложенных лэйаутов не совсем оптимально и может тормозить систему
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Намного практичнее использовать RelativeLayout
И "подсадить" еще три FAB слева от "базового" (размещенного в нижнем правом углу)
Исользуй android:layout_toLeftOf для размещения FAB слева от "базового", ну и margin, конечно чтобы FAB'ы не соприкасались)

Разметка (примерный набросок, не проверял в студии):

```
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ..............................................

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab1"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab2"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab3"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

В итоге получаем только один лэйаут

Comment: Решение хорошее, Но оно относительно базовой кнопки. Т.е. если на большем экране использовать, то оно будет где-то в начале и до центра не дойдет.

Comment: Какая разница какой экран? Все зависит ка краз от размещения "базовой кнопки"
В примере выше она помещается в нижний правый угол, причем тут размер экрана?
Следующая строка как раз это делает: app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
Остальные помещаются левее от нее

Давно пора переходить на RelativeLayout! Куча лэйаутов - это не круто

Comment: Если Вам нужно растянуть на весь экран эти четыре кнопки, тогда да, без LinearLayout не обойтись, но параметр weitht есть и у FAB, как минимум можно избавиться от FrameLayout'ов

И да, это решение не укладывается в концепцию MaterialDesign :)

Comment: та я, если честно, плевать хотел на концепцию материал) она не до конца продумана) это и гугл признают:)

Comment: голословно) Ну неважно, решение проблемы найдено

Comment: спасибо за помощь!)